# How can I return only two decimals when multiplying numbers?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, decimal

I have to multiply two decimal numbers: `6,0 * 5,50` which results in: `33,000`

How can I cut the last `0` off the result? I want to have `33,00` as the result.

To multiply, I use the query:

```
var rr = (from s in baza.customer
          where userID == s.userID
          && s.data.Month == dat
          select s.hours * s.prise.Sum();
```

Comment: actually shouldn't that just return 33 or are you expecting to return on 2 decimal places

Comment: You can format your output however you want with String.Format! Or I may not understand your question :-?

Comment: It would help if you could clarify whether your numbers are "6" and "5 and half" or "sixty" and "five hundred and fifty".

Comment: @user1031034 what are the declared types of s.hours and s.prise?  Also, have you confirmed in the debugger that the values are in fact 6 and 5+1/2?  It's possible that the values were parsed incorrectly at some point.  Also, where are you getting the result "33,000"?  Your code shows no formatting at all.

Comment: Can you run this -- `Console.WriteLine(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);` -- and put the output in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using string formatting for it: `string.Format("{0:0.##}", number)`.

Answer (score 4):

You have a character-set problem.  Your code is running in a North American locale, where `,` is a thousands separator (and `.` is the decimal marker).

Comment: It could also be a UK locale, or pretty much any other English-language locale.

Comment: It's got nothing to do with decimal separators. If it did, he wouldn't be getting the answer he did. This looks like a significant-digits issue with System.Decimal.

Comment: @JoeWhite Sixty multiplied by five hundred fifty is indeed thirty-three thousand, while six times five and a half is thirty three.  So it could in fact be a decimal separator issue.

Comment: @phoog: Unlikely - because "60" is incredibly unlikely to be formatted as "6,0". It would also make no sense of the requested result - why would the OP want a tenth of the real result? I don't think this answer is relevant to the real problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet My (en-US) machine parses "6,0" as 60, and "5,50" as 550; the formated result of the product is "33,000".  If the OP, however, uses ',' as the decimal separator, then the desired result is 33 with two decimal places and the actual result is (thought to be) 33 with three decimal places.

Comment: @phoog:  Code (& a test) that shows your claim would be extremely valuable here...

Comment: @AustinSalonen evaluate this expression with en-US locale: `(double.Parse("6,0") * double.Parse("5,50")).ToString("N0");`

Comment: @phoog: Yes, it will parse it that way - but what would be formatting it that way?

Comment: @phoog: The type is decimal, not double. Try `decimal x = 6.0m; decimal y =5.50m; Console.WriteLine(x * y);` Note that `double` doesn't retain insignificant decimal places; `decimal` does.

Comment: @JonSkeet Who knows?  The OP hasn't shown any code that formats the value `rr`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Aha, I see.  So 33 "point zero, zero zero" is the expected result of six times (five "point five, zero").  I did not realize.

Comment: @phoog: See my answer for more details, basically.

Answer (score 4):

As it seems there's some confusion here, I'll post a similar answer to two others, but with a short but complete program to show why it's necessary.

Firstly, it's worth clarifying that (as seen in comments) this is multiplying together two numbers less than 10 - as C# literals, they'd be 6.0m and 5.50m. The fact that they're `decimal` values is also highly relevant - as `decimal` maintains trailing zeroes, whereas `double` doesn't. So:

```
// Note: my system is in en-gb
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        decimal x = 6.0m;
        decimal y = 5.50m;
        decimal z = x * y;
        Console.WriteLine(z); // Prints 33.000
        Console.WriteLine(z.ToString("0.00")); // Prints 33.00
        // Same with composite formatting
        Console.WriteLine("{0:0.00}", z); // Still prints 33.00
        // If you want fewer than 2 decimal digits when they're
        // not necessary
        Console.WriteLine(z.ToString("0.##")); // Prints 33
    }
}
```

If the current thread's culture uses `','` instead of `'.'` as a decimal separator then obviously you'll get "33,00" instead.

If you want to round the *actual value* to 2 decimal places, you can do that with [`decimal.Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6be1edhb.aspx):

```
decimal rounded = decimal.Round(z, 2);
```

but of course this could lose significant information.

Note that you should usually *only* be applying string formatting when you're going to present the information to the user.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth asking as another question, but do you know why thousandths would be represented here when the most precise term only uses hundredths?

Comment: @AustinSalonen: It's not a matter of the most precise term: we have something with 2DP * something with 1DP, so the result has 3DP. Consider if the values were 0.12m and 0.1m - you would want an answer of 0.012m, wouldn't you?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you format the value at the time of output rather than try to cut decimals an the time of calculation?

Use

```
String.Format("{0:0.##}", number)
```

or

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", number)
```

to have only to decimals in your output.

Answer (score 0):

```
NumberFormat nf4 = new DecimalFormat("0000");
var rr=+nf6.format(new Integer(rr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the representation in string form, you need to format the result using the [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx). For example, after a quick test on the value you posted (33.000), the code `(33.000).ToString("f")` gave a result of 33.00.

Note: "f" may not be the actual format specifier you require - it would be best reading through the article I've linked first.

Comment: Those literals are `double` values, not `decimal`. It makes a big difference.